# Appending data in csv file problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
def append(new)
     user_file = open(r'users.csv', "a", newline = '')
     writer = csv.writer(user_file)
     writer.writerows(new)


#create a user list[... , ...]
append(user)
```

I tried to append rows in CSV file, and I can have the correct data in my list. However, the data in my CSV file has something wrong.

My original contents in CSV file:

```
admin, abcd
user1, qwer
```

I expect that my CSV file after running should like this:

```
admin, abcd
user1, qwer
appenduser, appendpassword
```

However, after running my program, my CSV file append like this:

```
admin, abcd
user1, qwer

a,p,p,e,n,d,u,s,e,r
a,p,p,e,n,d,p,a,s,s,w,o,r,d
```

What should I do in order to solve my problem? Appreciate for helps!

Comment: `writerows` iterates through the argument, thus it'll iterate through the string if thats what you're passing through, I suggest printing `new` inside the function to see if you're actually passing what you intend to be passing (as its unclear)

Answer (score 0):

Use `writerow`

**Ex:**

```
def append(new):
     user_file = open(r'users.csv', "a", newline = '')
     writer = csv.writer(user_file)
     writer.writerow(new)    

#create a user list[... , ...]
append(user)
```

Comment: Appreciate for your help and it works. And how about the newline after appending new data? How can I avoid it?

Comment: It will throw error if I use ab instead of a (binary mode doesn't take a newline argument)

Comment: Just `user_file = open(r'users.csv', "ab")`?

Comment: another error , a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: I have found solution. I use users_file = open(r'users.csv', "a", newline='\n')                    and it works.